# SQLite: how to enable counting number of rows modified from trigger

Tags: view, triggers, sqlite

is there any way to enable counting of rows that trigger modified in SQLite?

I know it is disabled https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html and i understand why, but can i enable it somehow?

```
CREATE TABLE Users_data (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT (0),
    Name STRING
);

CREATE VIEW Users AS 
    SELECT Id, Name 
    FROM Users_data 
    WHERE Deleted = 0;

CREATE TRIGGER UsersDelete2UsersData 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
ON Users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Users_data SET Deleted = 1 WHERE Id = OLD.Id; 
END;

-- etc for insert & update
```

then `delete from Users where Name like 'foo' /* doesnt even need 'Id = 1' */;` works fine, but numbers of modified rows is, as documentation say, always zero.

(I cant modify my DAL to automatically add "where Deleted = 0", so backup plan is to have table Users_deleted and 'on delete' trigger on Users table without any view, but then i have to keep tracking FKs (for example, what to do when someone delete from FK table) and so on...)

*Edit:* Returned number is used for checking on database concurrency.

*Edit2:* To be more clear: As i say, I can not modify my DAL (Entity Framework 6), so the preferred answer should operate as follow pseudo code: `int affectedRow = query("delete from Users where Name like 'foo';").Execute();`
Its all about SQLite "trigger on view" behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its imposible in sqlite3 (in 2015).

Basically I was looking for **instead of trigger on view** (as in question) with **return** function, *which is not supported* in sqlite.

By the way, postgresql (and i believe some others full db servers) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sqlite3_total_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/total_changes.html) instead:

> This function returns the total number of rows inserted, modified or deleted by all INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements completed since the database connection was opened, including those executed as part of trigger programs.

Comment: +1, but i can not accept as answer, (dont think i was clear in my question, so i will edit it) as i say, i cant modify my DAL, so i need something like (pseudo code) `int affectedRow = query("delete from Users where Name like 'foo'").Execute();`